# Directx changes

Tags: visual-studio, directx

i have a problem with win8 and directx library. i have directx jun 2010 i added its d3dx11.lib and .h files but it doesnt work and says library not found. i found hte link bellow that says you can work with win8 sdk instead of directx libraries and d3dx.... libraries are not supported anymore.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

i found in vs2012 there is a project that builds  directx proggram but when i made a project with it it wasnt like any directx code ive seen before its more like xna
what these really mean? how should i work with these changes? its better to return to win 7 and previous libraries or work with these new tools. thanks for helping

Comment: What kind of application are you building? The win8 sdk is probably required if you target app store. For desktop, older d3d sdks should work.

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan you mean if i set up win8 sdk d3dx libraries will be found in  visual studio? win 8 sdk is being downloaded. if older versions work in it why it says: library not found? what this link mean that directx now is a part of win8 sdk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"[Where is the DirectX SDK?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" explains that well. Probably you will want to read it one more time.

**D3DX**

[D3DX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D3DX) and D3D is not the same. D3DX is just a helper library. Microsoft not recommends to use D3DX anymore and stripped it from SDK. So now:

- **For new code**: "[Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx)" ([alternative link](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/)) explains what to use instead in your new code. And [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/10/29/codeplex-vs-2013-refresh.aspx) are some D3DX replacement stuff.
- **For old code**: if you just want to build old code that uses D3DX (tutorial samples, for example), you just need to install DirectX SDK and add include/lib paths to your project, as if it was any other library. Mixing Windows SDK and DirectX SDK is not recommended and can lead to errors, so don't use it in new code. Also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097823/building-with-xaudio2-on-windows-7/17107026#17107026).

Probably, you will be interested to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18111757/1607442) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179885/directx-in-windows-8-sdk/17184487#17184487) answer also.

**P.S.** As always, if linker says, "Library not found", double check, that you've added library path to project options and that library file exists at that folder.

Happy coding!

Comment: Living without D3DX is dead.